# SPAPI_Core.js access denied

Tags: javascript

I have old web page which I am trying to set up on new sharepoint site, is uses SPAPI_Core.js, but I am getting access denied error to this js library. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Odds are wherever you are storing the .js file isn't available for read. Check the permissions.